# Internal server error (500) with a simple .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to enable caching for images and the like on my web server, so I made this `.htaccess` file, but my web server says Internal Error 500.

Here's the file, which looks fine to me...

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine on my own server, so there are no errors in there...
Perhaps mod_headers is not enabled? Or maybe you used some strange encoding that Apache does not understand? What if you just copy-paste this into a new file and overwrite the existing one?

Comment: Turns out my webhost didn't have `mod_headers` enabled, now it works.

Answer (score -1):

**you need to check if  mod_rewrite module in apache is loaded.
here is directions how to do it:**

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/check-enable-mod_rewrite-apache.html

Comment: This particular directive has nothing to do with mod_rewrite, this is about mod_header.